# R: Two X arguments in grep

Tags: r

As far as I know I can search for one of the two desired "pattern" arguments in grep if I write `pattern1|Pattern2`.

But I don't know how to find them in either `X` arguments that I have.
If I write them separately, like this:

```
grep(pattern1|Pattern2,X1)
grep(pattern1|Pattern2,X2)
```

they work, but I need something like:

```
grep(pattern1|Pattern2,X1|X2)
```

But I have the error below:

> operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try an approach like this one:

```
X1<-"try this example!"
X2<-"try this other!"

X<-c(X1,X2)

any(grepl("example|other",X))
    [1] TRUE
```

Credit to @Andrew Gustar about the optimization

Comment: You could wrap this in `any` or `all`.  So for the `X1|X2` case, use `any(grepl("example|other",X))`